# Multi-entity aliases in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have two entities `Units` and `UnitTypes`:

```
public class Units 
{
    public Units()
    {
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        public int UnitTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}

public class UnitTypes
{
    public UnitTypes()
    {
        public int FruitTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to have generic alias functionality for the columns `name` and `description`. This alias can be based on language. I know there are other ways to do translation, but we require also other aliases which could be specific to a role or user for example. I had the following entity in mind for the alias model:

| AliasId | Entity | Column | EntityId (not a FK) | Language | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `{Guid}` | Units | Name | Guid | en-EN | Pear |
| `{Guid}` | Units | Name | Guid | nl-NL | Peer |
| `{Guid}` | UnitTypes | Name | Guid | en-EN | Fruit |
| `{Guid}` | UnitTypes | Description | Guid | en-EN | Fruit |

I would like to access and use the aliases in a LINQ preferably in a single-trip.
Could I add aliases using a custom written extension method?

```
var unit = await units.GetAll()
                      .Where(u => u.UnitId == request.UnitId)
                      .Select(u => new UnitDetailQueryModel()
                                      {
                                          UnitId = u.UnitId,
                                          Name = u.Name.GetAlias(),
                                          Description = u.Description.GetAlias(),        
                                          UnitTypeId = u.UnitTypeId,
                                          UnitTypeName = u.UnitType.Name.GetAlias(),
                                          UnitTypeDescription = u.UnitType.Description.GetAlias(),
                                      })
                      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: If your project has only several such queries, don't even try to do that - write LINQ query with LEFT join and retrieve aliases by the hands. Implementation and debugging common solution needs strong ExpressionTree knowledge and several days for implementation.

Comment: But if you still need that I can give you advice what you have to solve to achieve goal.

Comment: Yes this functionality should by preference be generic, as I have too many similar queries to extend each one. I am also looking at a db view (code first style) which already has the join. In this example I'd use the view instead of the original entity.